# TFS or other Bug Tracking Suggestions

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, bug-tracking

I currently work for a small web development company that provides an online ASP.NET web application. Currently we handle bugs by sending out an email to all of our developers and having them look into them manually.

What we're looking for is a more automated way of tracking and monitoring this process by actually categorizing and reporting to management the types and quantity of bugs coming in on a weekly/monthly/quarterly basis.

We have a Customer Facing help desk that monitors the types of Support Requests come in and the frequency and from this data we create our reports.

Ideally what we'd like is a bug tracking system that allows us to gather this same type of data around the bugs that are in our system. Management is looking for a report that we can generate showing frequency and occurrence of different types of bugs.

Is there a way to use TFS for this?

Comment: I removed the parts asking for opinions and software recommendations, otherwise this bordered on being off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many systems that can do what you are looking for, including Visual Studio ALM (TFS). It really depends on what else you want as well.

http://nakedalm.com/why-should-i-use-visual-studio-alm-whether-tfs-or-vso/

If you only want bug tracking and you don't keep your code in source control, or don't manage your requirements then you can use TFS. However you would also get value from associations between code and bugs. Can you, or do you want to, answer: What parts of my code generate the most bugs?